# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.access.AccessType while deploying spring/hibernate application in Jetty

Tags: spring, hibernate, jetty

HI I am trying to deploy my app in Jetty and get the following error ,The app has a module pumpkinservice that depends upon a hibernate module pumpkinstore.

```
2012-11-10 11:10:01.138:WARN::Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/pumpkinsafari,file:/C:/Users/Gaurav/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8081-pumpkinservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_pumpkinsafari-
any-/webapp/},C:/Users/Gaurav/.m2/repository/com/pumpkinsafari/service/pumpkinservice/1.0-SNAPSHOT/pumpkinservice-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Gaurav/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8081-pumpkinservice-1.0-SNAPSH
OT.war-_pumpkinsafari-any-/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/pumpkinstore-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/pumpkinsafari/store/model/Customer.class]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/acc
ess/AccessType;
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:261)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:84)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:73)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1419)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1409)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:184)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:140)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:111)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:493)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:118)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:294)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:622)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:451)
```

.Though when I try to run my isolated test cases they work .

My pom is as below

parent pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pumpkinstore.pumpkinparent</groupId>
    <artifactId>pumpkinparent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>pumpkin-parent</name>

    <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.12.3</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

    </build>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate-core.version>4.1.7.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <hibernate-search.version>4.1.1.Final</hibernate-search.version>
        <hibernate-commons.version>3.5.6-Final</hibernate-commons.version>
        <hibernate-commons-annotation.version>3.2.0.Final</hibernate-commons-annotation.version>
        <hibernate-jpa.version>2.0-cr-1</hibernate-jpa.version>
        <junit.version>4.10</junit.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.21</mysql.version>
        <sl4j.version>1.6.4</sl4j.version>
        <dom4j.version>1.6.1</dom4j.version>
        <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
        <ehcache.version>2.4.3</ehcache.version>
        <antlr.version>2.7.7</antlr.version>
        <javassist.version>3.12.1.GA</javassist.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.0</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-logging.version>1.1.1</commons-logging.version>
        <commons-collection.version>3.2.1</commons-collection.version>
        <guava.version>r09</guava.version>
        <spring-security.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring-security.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>
        <jackson-mapper-asl.version>1.9.9</jackson-mapper-asl.version>
        <jaxb-api.version>2.2.7</jaxb-api.version>
        <cglib.version>2.2.2</cglib.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>apache-snapshot</id>
            <name>Apache Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <modules>
        <module>PumpkinService</module>
        <module>PumpkinStore</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

pumpmkinstore pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pumpkinsafari.store</groupId>
    <artifactId>pumpkinstore</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pumpkinstore</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pumpkinstore.pumpkinparent</groupId>
        <artifactId>pumpkinparent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>

        <!-- JUnit testing framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring AOP dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Hibernate Core framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate Annotation framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-commons-annotation.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate Common Annotation framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-commons.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate Search framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-search.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>${jta.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-logging.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-collection.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>${dom4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->
        <!-- marshalling -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>pumpkinstore</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please Help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're having issues with incompatible Hibernate jars. This is probably happening because you're specifying dependencies which are pulled in transitively by Maven and you are manually specifying the version of these jars which are not compatible with each other.

You only need to depend on hibernate-core. So replace all of this:

```
    <!-- Hibernate Core framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate Annotation framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-commons-annotation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate Common Annotation framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.java-persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>${jta.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

with:

```
 <!-- Hibernate Core framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex Ya I had figured it out It seems that Hibernate annotation is not required for Hibernate 4 after removing the dependecies everything worked fine .